# AsyncTask/Handler lagging UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I have this AsyncTask that gets data from a website, and on it's post execute it calls a main function to setText for main's textview.

Here is the code.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {     
    result = connect(start);//connect to the webpage, start is a URL
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(this.result);
    Elements stuff = doc.select("td");

    MainActivity.GetData(doc);//set the textview
}
```

I call a handler to do this every five seconds, here is the handler code.

```
hand = new Handler();       
r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            dh  = new DownloadHelper("http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/psi-readings-over-the-last-24-hours");
            dh.execute("");// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hand.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };

hand.post(r);
```

What happens is, when the website is loading, my UI lags a lot, almost to the point of freezing. I have no idea what is causing this, my UI is based on a ViewPager, with fragments.

I am not running this code from the fragment though, it is running from the onCreate of my main activity.

EDIT: I edited my onPostExecute to look like this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    super.onPostExecute(result);

        Elements stuff = doc.select("td");
    String[] arr = new String[stuff.size()];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++)
    {

        arr[i] = stuff.get(79 + i).text();

    }

    MainActivity.GetData(arr);
    MainActivity.dismissLoading();
}
```

This is my GetData

```
public static void GetData(String[] s)
{

 edit.setText(s[0]);




}
```

This is connect()

```
public static String connect(String l)
{

    String url = l;
    HttpURLConnection connect;
    String result;
    String result2 = null;
    BufferedReader br;

    try {
        connect = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        while ((result = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
             result2 += result;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("ERROR");
    }
    return result2;

}
```

Comment: have you tried executing `Jsoup.parse(this.result)` inside `doInBackground`?

Comment: Parsing and reading of files should also be done in a non ui thread. Try moving the call to parse() inside doInBackground()

Comment: @SaurabhVerma I tried that, and it still lagged.. could it be because the handler is creating a new AsyncTask every 10 seconds? ( I got it wrong in my post, it's 10 seconds not 5)

Comment: 1) Move the parse call to `doInBackground`
2) Show us GetData() and connect()

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to get data every 5 seconds? You will still have network connections open from the prior run if you are on a lower bandwidth environment.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Well the app is supposed to fetch data from a php site in as real time as possible, so I figured 5 seconds was the most real time I could go.

Comment: Unless the site is updating the data every 10 seconds there is no point to do that. I would (a) find out how frequently the data updates (b) start with a less frequent interval. A quick look at the url implies to me its an hourly update (perhaps).

Comment: @MorrisonChang The website that I posted was simply for testing purposes, in my school project we will simply create a small php website that will be hosted on the internet, and we will try to update it as 'realtime' as possible.

Comment: Well unless your php website has the same content, the time to parse will be different between your 'test' and 'real' site. Its easier to parse a site with just a kilobyte of data than one with hundreds. Best to create a mock site with the data you are interested in and use that for testing.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Okay I just managed to set up a website that will be similar to my project, and to my amazement the app stopped freezing, everything worked perfectly. I'm still using AsyncTask

But even so, it still puzzles me why AsyncTask is causing the lag.

Comment: If you are still using the same code as in the question, your parsing routine is on the UI thread - get it off the UI thread. If the data is small, you won't have problems, as the data gets bigger it will lock up the UI thread, and/or take longer than 5/10 seconds before your next request arrives.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who actually stumbled upon my problem and wanted an answer, I managed to fix it while working on another project.

Basically, in the

```
   while ((result = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
         result2 += result;
    }
```

loop, instead of appending result to result2 directly, append result to a StringBuffer. Then at the end of the loop, add back the StringBuffer to result2.