# Besides AsyncTask, is there anyway in Android to do something on the UI thread from another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Because for some strange reasons, when I use AsyncTask to connect to a webpage, the UI of my app lags to almost the point of freezing while the AsyncTask is connecting to the webpage.

I thought this was because the connection usually takes quite long, at least 4 seconds.

I want to be able to update my TextView after my Thread have finished, but how do I do that in Android besides using AsyncTask?

Comment: you can use a thread and use `runonUithread` to update ui.

Comment: You can use [runOnUiThread or Handlers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html). But if you post your `AsyncTask` we may be able to see why it is lagging and if there's a way to fix what you have

Comment: @codeMagic I posted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855919/asynctask-handler-lagging-ui

but unfortunately despite the help my UI is still lagging.

Comment: post your asynctask code,  maybe it can be optimised.

Comment: @forgivegod http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855919/asynctask-handler-lagging-ui

Would be nice if someone can solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to do that:

- Use Threads or Runnables
- Use Handlers, sending messages to its
- Use RunOnUIThread method
- Use the method (this is my favorite) post. It's not necessary to use a context/activity instance

For example, you can create a new Handler() and when you want to run code in the main thread do:

```
  public static Handler interfaceHandler = new Handler();

 ...

  mInterfaceHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your stuff
        }
    });
```

To complete the information, all Views in Android can make this post(Runnable) . This method add a runnable to their task to do, for that reason is recommendable not use views because the App will slow down. The static handler is perfect to make this work and is very easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            // do some stuff here
       }
   });
```